# Return Value of Binary Search

Tags: java

I created a program that generates a random 10 number array, sorts the array with a bubble sort, and then uses a binary search to see if the value is in the array or not. All my code looks correct to me, but everytime I run the program if the number I choose to search for is infact in the array it still tells me it's not. I believe it has something to do with my return value, but the code looks right to me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE=10;
        int[] numbers= new int[SIZE];
        int number;
        int result;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        loadArray(numbers);
        sortArray(numbers);
        displayArray(numbers);
        System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
        number=keyboard.nextInt();
        result=binarySearch(numbers, number);
        if(result==-1){
            System.out.print("Your number was not found");
        }else{
            System.out.print("Your number was found");
        }
    }
    public static void loadArray(int[] numbers){
        int index;
        for(index=0;index<numbers.length;index++){
            numbers[index]=(int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
        }
    }
    public static void sortArray(int[] num){
        int index;
        int passNo;
        int holdingnumber;
        //boolean condition=true;
        //while(condition){
            //condition=false;
        for(passNo=0;passNo<num.length-1;passNo++){ 
            for(index=0;index<num.length-1;index++){
                if(num[index]>num[index+1]){
                    holdingnumber=num[index+1];
                    num[index+1]=num[index];
                    num[index]=holdingnumber;
                    //condition=true;  
                } 
            }
         } 

    }
    public static void displayArray(int[] numbers){
        int index;
        for(index=0;index<numbers.length;index++){
            System.out.println("Element["+index+"]: " +numbers[index]);
        }
    }
    public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int number){
        int low=0;
        int mid=0;
        int high=0;
        while(low<=high){
            mid=(low+high)/2;
            if(array[mid]>number){
                high=mid-1;
            }else if(array[mid]<number){
                low=mid+1;
            }else{
                return mid;   
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you only search on [low;high] i.e in index 0

Comment: @RiaD Well this sort of looks like an assignment, so I imagine they have to implement their own.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, I see. But I found it's important to remind that there is standard way and OP should consider using it when it will use it in his real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `high` variable not equal  0 , it need to be the Length of the array Like this :

```
  int high = array.length-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Examine your binary search method:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int number){
    int low=0;
    int mid=0;
    int high=0;
    while(low<=high){
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(array[mid]>number){
            high=mid-1;
        }else if(array[mid]<number){
            low=mid+1;
        }else{
            return mid;   
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You need to have high start as the last index of the array. Your code examines the index values between 0 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `high`  It searches between 0 and 0